# Strange program behavior

Tags: c++

So I wanted to write code which solves this problem: "[Collecting Beepers](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=654&problem=1437&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2014739312)"
And I did:

```
int rec(int current, int beers)
{
    if(beers == (1 << (numOfBeers + 1)) - 1) return cost(beerX[0], beerY[0], beerX[current], beerY[current]);
    int optimal = 100000;
    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfBeers; ++i)
    {
        if(((1 << i) & beers) == 0)
        {
            int newBeersSet = (1 << i) | beers;
            int c = cost(beerX[current], beerY[current], beerX[i], beerY[i]);
            int current = c + rec(i, newBeersSet);
            optimal = min(optimal, current);
        }
    }
    return optimal;
}
```

The strange thing is, that when I replace the part

```
int c = cost(beerX[current], beerY[current], beerX[i], beerY[i]);
int current = c + rec(i, newBeersSet);
```

with

```
int current = cost(beerX[current], beerY[current], beerX[i], beerY[i]) + rec(i, newBeersSet);
```

the logic is absolutely the same and yet my program crashes on the same (the one given in the problem desciption) input and the online judge gives wrong answer as a result from the program execution while with the original code it gives Accepted. Any ideas what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that `cost` is still being called before `rec`?

Comment: Which line is it crashing on, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is propably because your variable "current" is overriden. Try:

```
int current2 = cost(beerX[current], beerY[current], beerX[i], beerY[i]) + rec(i, newBeersSet);
optimal = min(optimal, current2);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line you are using an uninitialized variable:

```
int current = cost(beerX[current],  // ...
```

This declares a new variable `current` and then, before the variable has had a value assigned, uses it as index to `beerX`.

You probably meant:

```
int new_current = cost(beerX[current],  // ...
```

which uses the existing `current` variable which was declared in the parameter list for the `rec` function.